# Restoring a differential backup in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, backup, restore

I have created a full back up of my database  by executing the line below in my application:

```
Dim Query As String = "backup database Ari to disk='G:\Documents and Settings\i\Desktop\BKAR\" & MyTime.getFullCurrentDate.Replace("/", "") & ".Bak'"
```

The *.bak file created successfully.

Then I restored it on another Database called test and it was ok.
Then I created a Differential backup by means of the following code:

```
Dim Query As String = "BACKUP DATABASE Ari TO DISK='G:\Documents and Settings\i\Desktop\BKAR\" & MyTime.getFullCurrentDate.Replace("/", "") & ".Bak'" & "WITH DIFFERENTIAL"
```

and it created a *.bak file ,but when I try to restore it on the database I mentioned as test ,I receive the following error:
[image]

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown us your [`RESTORE DATABASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) command, but you appear to have omitted a recovery option, or specified `WITH RECOVERY` (which is the default). In either case, if you've done that, you cannot apply any further backups.

If you want to apply a series of backups, you need to specify [`WITH NORECOVERY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bfe5734-3003-4165-afd4-b1131ea26e2b) on all (or all but the last) of the `RESTORE`s.